# How to get three different types of score for each text in one row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a new SQL developer and I am trying to write a query that will retrieve the following results from three tables in the database:

> ID    Text    Score #1    Score #2    Score #3

The schema for the three tables are:

```
T_TextScore Table: Id, TextId, Label, Score, TypeId
T_Text: Id, Text
T_Status Table: Id, Type
```

The T_TextScore table contains three different types of scroes for each text. I was able to retrieve the scores for all texts but I am still unable to show each type of score for each text in one row as illustrated above. **So could you please tell me how I can get the desired result?**

Here's the query I have and I think it is not efficient in terms of performance as well:

```
SELECT        T_TextScore.TextId, T_Text.Text, T_TextScore.Label, T_TextScore.Score
FROM            T_TextScore INNER JOIN
                         T_Text ON T_TextScore.TextId = T_Text.Id
WHERE        (T_TextScore.TypeId = 3)
UNION
SELECT        T_TextScore.TextId, T_Text.Text, T_TextScore.Label, T_TextScore.Score
FROM            T_TextScore INNER JOIN
                         T_Text ON T_TextScore.TextId = T_Text.Id
WHERE        (T_TextScore.TypeId = 4)
UNION
SELECT        T_TextScore.TextId, T_Text.Text, T_TextScore.Label, T_TextScore.Score
FROM            T_TextScore INNER JOIN
                         T_Text ON T_TextScore.TextId = T_Text.Id
WHERE        (T_TextScore.TypeId = 5);
```

UPDATE:
After using the query suggested by @Craig Young, I got two rows for each text and I don't know why. Could you please explain to me why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut820.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is Score 1?  What are the type ids in your example code?

Comment: @Tech Don't include images of data. Rather copy/paste the text (it's more useful as text ***and*** it's smaller). As to your update, it's difficult to determine exactly what's wrong because you haven't included source data in your question (as Gordon originally requested). However, I did realise there was a small mistake on my answer, and I've updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query isn't doing quite what you asked for. The following would be a much better way of doing what you're currently doing:

```
SELECT  ts.TextId, t.Text, ts.Label, ts.Score
FROM    T_TextScore ts /* Table alias makes query much more readable */
        INNER JOIN T_Text t ON
            ts.TextId = t.Id
WHERE   ts.TypeId IN (3, 4, 5)
```

However, the first part of your question suggests you actually want to pivot your data?

If so you can use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) syntax. Or manual pivoting:

```
SELECT  ts.TextId,
        /* Use aggregate function to get only 1 per TextId */
        MAX(t.Text) AS Text, MAX((ts.Label) AS Label,
        /* Simply move ts.Score to the correct column to be summed. */
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.TypeId = 3 THEN ts.Score ELSE 0 END) AS Score3,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.TypeId = 4 THEN ts.Score ELSE 0 END) AS Score4,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.TypeId = 5 THEN ts.Score ELSE 0 END) AS Score5
FROM    T_TextScore ts
        INNER JOIN T_Text t ON
            ts.TextId = t.Id
WHERE   ts.TypeId IN (3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY ts.TextId
```

NOTE: PIVOT syntax is a little more succinct. But strangely I have seen it run slightly slower than manual pivot on occasion. So if performance is important, you'll have to benchmark.

---

Based on your comment:

> After using the query suggested by @Craig Young, I got two rows for each text and I don't know why.

You probably either removed the GROUP BY clause, or included `Text` and `Label` in the GROUP BY. This made me realise that I'd forgotten to deal with these 2 columns which weren't part of either aggregate or GROUP BY.

I've updated my query above appropriately. However, I should point out lack of sample data makes it tricky to determine exactly what you're trying to achieve - particularly with the `Label` column which could be different per Score Type.

Comment: thanks for your help in this regard. I really like your second query related to the Pivot table. However, when I tried it, I got two rows for each text and I don't know why. Please have a look at the updates in my question.

Comment: thank you very much for your great help in this matter. I apologize for not giving more accurate information in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You want conditional aggregation.  My best guess is simply:

```
SELECT ts.TextId, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN ts.TypeId = 3 THEN ts.Score END) as Score_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ts.TypeId = 4 THEN ts.Score END) as Score_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ts.TypeId = 5 THEN ts.Score END) as Score_3
FROM T_TextScore ts 
GROUP BY ts.TextId;
```